# Sorting Card objects

Tags: java, comparator

I'm creating a simple card game and I want to be able to sort an `ArrayList<Card>` so that the players hand is easier to read. Right now I have:

Card class:

```
public class Card implements Comparable {

public enum Suits {
    SPADES,
    CLUBS,
    HEARTS,
    DIAMONDS
}

public enum Values {
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    FIVE,
    SIX,
    SEVEN,
    EIGHT,
    NINE,
    TEN,
    JACK,
    QUEEN,
    KING,
    ACE, 
}

private Suits suit;
private Values value;

public Card(final Values value, final Suits suit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public Values getValue() {
    return value;
}

public Suits getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void showCard() {
    value = getValue();
    suit = getSuit();

    System.out.println(value + " of " + suit);
}

public int compareTo(final Object compareCard) {
    Card compareToCard = (Card) compareCard;
    Suits thisSuit = this.suit;
    Values thisValue = this.value;

    if (thisSuit.ordinal() == compareToCard.getSuit().ordinal() &&
        thisValue.ordinal() == compareToCard.getValue().ordinal()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (thisSuit.ordinal() == compareToCard.getSuit().ordinal()) {
        if (thisValue.ordinal() > compareToCard.getValue().ordinal()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

}
```

I used the `ordinal` values since I want to order the Values 2-Ace and it doesn't really matter which order the Suits are in as long as they are grouped together.

Then I have an `ArrayList<Card>` called `playerHand`. I am trying to sort using:

```
playerHand.sort();
```

When I go to compile this code I am receiving an error:

```
error: method sort in interface List<E> cannot be applied to given types;
    playerHand.sort();
              ^
  required: Comparator<? super Card>
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
```

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should use comparator not comparable?

Comment: Read about Comparator

Comment: You can't just return `-1` whenever the suits don't match. It's very important that `Math.signum(a.compareTo(b)) == -Math.signum(b.compareTo(a))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement Comparable interface, like this:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
```

Comment: he does implement it but not the generic one

Comment: @user2397162 he implements generic Comparable without class indication

Comment: I made the change from `Object` to `Card` and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @RyanSayles I suppose you need to call `Collections.sort(playerHand);` instead of `playerHand.sort();`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I have some more work to do on my compareTo method to get it working properly but it does sort it with no errors

Comment: Implementing `Comparable` or `Comparable<Object>` doesn't result in any warnings or errors. It's just a little inconvenient to cast the `(Card) other` card.

Answer (score 1):

define this class outside your card class:

```
class CardComparator implements Comparator<Card>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Card o1, Card o2) 
    {
         if (o1.getSuit().ordinal() == o2.getSuit().ordinal() && o1.getValue().ordinal() == o2.getValue().ordinal()) 
         {
             return 0;
         }
         else if (o1.getSuit().ordinal() ==o2.getSuit().ordinal()) 
         {
             if (o1.getValue().ordinal() > o2.getValue().ordinal())
                 return 1;                 
             else                  
                 return -1;                
         }
         else
             return -1;    
    }

}
```

and then call the sort method like this:

```
playerHand.sort(new CardComparator());
```

just don't forget to import java.util.Comparator.

Comment: Would a `Comparator.naturalOrder()` sort the same way as a `new CardComparator()` does?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work as supposed(sorting wrong)

Comment: but it doesn't give any exceptions so you could use it in cases different from yours

Comment: I just found the time to check it. Both versions sort wrong in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite informative.

```
required: Comparator<? super Card>
found: no arguments
```

Method `sort` in interface `List` expects an argument but you didn't pass one. This argument can either be a `Comparator` or `null` and tells the method how to sort the list.

You already implemented the interface `Comparable`. But this only *defines* the *natural order* of the cards. If you want to sort by this order you either pass `Comparator.naturalOrder()` or simply `null`. But if you wanted to sort the cards in reverse natural order you would pass `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

You could even go so far and create two separate `SuitComparator implements Comparator<Card>` and `ValueComparator implements Comparator<Card>` and be able to combine these in different ways. For example the following would recreate the natural order:
`new SuitComparator().thenComparing(new ValueComparator())`